# "no matching function for call to min_element" when using a vector of CvPoints (opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv

Here's my function to retrieve the corners of a rectangle, the input is a thresholded image (with a numberplate on it) and I want the output to be a vector (within a vector) with the cornerpoints of the plate. Ordered: left_up, right_up, right_bottom, left_bottom.

I use openCV to find the contours (which works fine); after some filters, I use approxPoly to find rectangles. I find four points, which is great, but I want to order them. I thought the following would work:
put all the point in a vector

find min_element specified by compare function Left and erase from vector

find another left element and erase, then determine which is up and which is down.

the remaining two points are the right points.

```
bool left(CvPoint &pt1, CvPoint &pt2) {
    return pt1.x < pt2.x;
}

bool up(CvPoint &pt1, CvPoint &pt2) {
    return pt1.y < pt2.y;
}

std::vector<std::vector<CvPoint> > findNumberPlate(IplImage* img) {

vector<CvPoint> numberplate;
vector<vector<CvPoint> > numberplates_output;

CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvMemStorage* storage2 = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* contour = 0;
cvFindContours(img, storage, &contour, sizeof (CvContour), CV_RETR_EXTERNAL);
CvSeq* result = 0;

for (CvSeq* c = contour; c != NULL; c = c->h_next) {

    double area_contour = cvContourArea(c, CV_WHOLE_SEQ);
    CvBox2D c_box = cvMinAreaRect2(c);
    double area_box = c_box.size.height * c_box.size.width;

    if (area_contour / area_box > 0.83 && area_contour > 2000) {

        if (!storage2 == 0) cvClearMemStorage(storage2);
        else storage2 = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
        result = cvApproxPoly(c, sizeof (CvContour), storage2, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(c)*0.03, 0);

        if (result->total == 4) {

            //find up/bottom & left/right                
            vector<CvPoint> points;

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                CvPoint* tempPoint = (CvPoint*) cvGetSeqElem(result, i);
                points.push_back(cvPoint(tempPoint->x,tempPoint->y));
            }

            vector<CvPoint>::iterator itLeft1 = std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end(), left);
            points.erase(itLeft1);
            vector<CvPoint>::iterator itLeft2 = std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end(), left);
            points.erase(itLeft2);

            vector<CvPoint>::iterator itLeftUp = std::min(itLeft1, itLeft2, left);
            vector<CvPoint>::iterator itLeftBottom = std::max(itLeft1, itLeft2, left);
            CvPoint left_up = *itLeftUp;
            CvPoint left_bottom = *itLeftBottom;

            vector<CvPoint>::iterator itRightUp = std::min(points.begin(), points.end(), up);
            vector<CvPoint>::iterator itRightBottom = std::max(points.begin(), points.end(), up);
            CvPoint right_up = *itRightUp;
            CvPoint right_bottom = *itRightBottom;

//etc
}
```

However, when using the function min_element & max_element I get several errors I don't understand.

```
findNumberPlate.cpp:57: error: no matching function for call to ‘min_element(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CvPoint*, std::vector<CvPoint, std::allocator<CvPoint> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CvPoint*, std::vector<CvPoint, std::allocator<CvPoint> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
findNumberPlate.cpp:59: error: no matching function for call to ‘min_element(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CvPoint*, std::vector<CvPoint, std::allocator<CvPoint> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CvPoint*, std::vector<CvPoint, std::allocator<CvPoint> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
findNumberPlate.cpp:62: error: no matching function for call to ‘min(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CvPoint*, std::vector<CvPoint, std::allocator<CvPoint> > >&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CvPoint*, std::vector<CvPoint, std::allocator<CvPoint> > >&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
findNumberPlate.cpp:63: error: no matching function for call to ‘max(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CvPoint*, std::vector<CvPoint, std::allocator<CvPoint> > >&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CvPoint*, std::vector<CvPoint, std::allocator<CvPoint> > >&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

Can't I use CvPoints with min_element? Or... Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: first, you're using cpp but not new opencv c++ interface. second: have you importend `#include <algorithm>` ?

Comment: I included:#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

Comment: Sorry, I believe I gave you the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it becomes very clear that there is [another overloaded function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) with same name `left`, hence the compiler is unable to resolve which one you mean when you pass `left` as third argument to `std::min_element`.

So the solution is to help the compiler to disambiguate the situation as:

```
auto min = std::min_element(points.begin(), 
                            points.end(), 
                            static_cast<bool(*)(CvPoint&,CvPoint&)>(left) );
```

Well that looks cumbersome, so you can simplify it as:

```
bool (*leftptr)(CvPoint&,CvPoint&) = left; //compiler chooses the correct overload
auto min = std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end(), leftptr);
```

Or, this:

```
typedef bool (*left_type)(CvPoint&,CvPoint&);

left_type leftptr = left; //compiler chooses the correct overload
auto min = std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end(), leftptr);
```

In all these cases, the compiler chooses the correct overload based on the *target* type, be it in the `static_cast`, or in the `leftptr` declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Why are you using 'auto'? Just to check if I understand you: could I also 'just' change the name of my compare function? (i.e. to leftpoint)

Comment: it works for min_element! However, for min(), when entering two cvPoints, it does not work. conversion from ‘const CvPoint’ to non-scalar type ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CvPoint*, std::vector<CvPoint, std::allocator<CvPoint> > >’ requested

Comment: @Rogier: With `min`, you want to compare values, not iterators. `CvPoint left_up = std::min(*itLeft1, *itLeft2, left);`

Comment: @MikeSeymour thanks! I tried that, but it gives an error: In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/algorithm:61,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:56,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h:64,
                 from findNumberPlate.h:11,
                 from findNumberPlate.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algobase.h:235: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘CvPoint&’ from expression of type ‘const CvPoint’

Comment: @Rogier: That's because your comparators take their arguments by non-const reference. Changing them to `bool(CvPoint const &pt1, CvPoint const &pt2)` should fix that.

Comment: Thanks everybody for helping! @nawaz: I changed the compare name and than it worked! Thanks for explaining :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I couldn't get the min() function to work with CvPoints, but I just compared the y values... And it's not even Workaround-Wednesday! ;) Thanks again!